# Datables: Two tables from ajax

Tags: php, datatables

What is the best way of fetching data from two tables on an ajax source?

I am using datables like:

```
$('#user_types').dataTable({
            'bServerSide' : true,
            'bProcessing' : true,
            'sAjaxSource' : 'datatables/ajax_file.php',
            'iDisplayLength' : 50,  
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage":{
                    "sSearch": "",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Limit: _MENU_"
                },
            'aaSorting': [[3, 'desc']],
            'aoColumns' : [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {'bSortable' : false},
            ]
        })
```

Now, on ajax_file.php, I am reading all the info from one table. Now I need to get a column from another table, how can I do so?

Comment: Table-row-gateway/active record pattern in Javascript?  Well suppose a dirty answer to your question is to create a database view.  Then your fragile utopia of object===table won't be shattered. Is this some known ORM in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query in your `datatables/ajax_file.php` from a 'normal' select query into a query with a `JOIN` or `UNION` , joining the tables you want to display together.